# How to name a struct based on a char variable in c programming

Tags: c, struct

I am seeking help into how I can name a struct using a char variable.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct user {
char name[50];
int age;
char hobby[50];
};

int main()
{
    char nameVar[50];
    int ageVar;
    char hobbyVar[50];

    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf("%s", nameVar);
    return 0;
}
```

And here i would like name the struct based on the variable nameVar.
Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Why? If you're just having a single "user" then name it something that is easy for you as the programmer to remember, as `struct user user;`? And if you need multiple user structures, create an array as like `struct user users[X];` (where `X` is the max number of users).

Comment: Ok. Good point. Will try it as soon as possible! Thank you very much.

Comment: But is there a way to do it?? I am just curious?

Comment: No, you can't use run-time data (like a string from user-input) for naming of variables.

Comment: If the name of your variables wasn't known, how would you refer to them (to print for example)? If I understand what you want, that is impossible; and would serve no purpose in real life. After scanf you'd have a brand new variable identified with `John` or `Mary` or `Joe` or `...`

Comment: Thank you very much. I highly appreciate you help.

Comment: Variable names exist for the benefit of the programmer, not for the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in C. This is possible in many interpreted languages, but for compiling languages - like C - it is rare, if it does exist at all.

What you can do to mimic this is to have some kind of dictionary. Of course, you would have to either find a library for that or code your own, but something like this is possible:

```
void add_to_dict(const char *str);
struct user get_element_from_dict(const char *str);

int main()
{
    printf("What is your name?");
    scanf("%s", nameVar);
    add_to_dict(nameVar);
    struct user myUser = get_element_from_dict(nameVar);
    printf("Name, age and hobby: %s %d %s\n" myUser.name, myUser.age, myUser.hobby);
}
```